# Vite Js --> dev mode works, but build doesn't. (importing library causes error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vite

I tried to move from vue-cli to vite but observed some obstacles.

I want to include several npm packages into my vue 3 project.
I tried to understand the issue, and basically the error came when I imported
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rdf-parse

If I run `npm run dev` everything works as expected, but when I run `npm run build` and serve the dist folder with `http-server` the error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object at Function.defineProperty`
occurs.

The code worked with vue-cli and in vite-dev mode so I expect I missed somethin crucial in the `vite.config.js`
But I didnt find anything in the docu that helped me out and also no thread here on stackoverflow or elsewhere.

I created a repo with a minimal example here: https://github.com/stackoverflowuser/vite-issue

It is the npm vue3 template (`npm init vue@3`) and only the library rdf-parse is added.

```
// vite.config.js

import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    }
  },

  build: {
    target: "es2020"
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
        // Limit target browsers due to issue: Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari13" + 2 overrides)'
        target: "es2020",
            // Node.js global to browser globalThis
            define: {
              global: 'globalThis'
          },
          // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
          plugins: [
              NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin()
          ]

    }
},
})
```

In hope someone can give me a hint.

Comment: can you pinpoint the error to a specific line of code? also, why do you need `NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin` - I've never needed that in a vue3 project

Comment: Sure, it is here https://github.com/stackoverflowuser/vite-issue/blob/main/src/App.vue In line 4 and 5. Actually the import only already causes the problem.

I used NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin because my browser was blaming me `Module "util" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "util.debuglog" in client code.` When I used the Polyfill Plugin this error was gone. Of coure only in dev mode again, build never worked

Comment: So, you get the error *In line 4 **and** 5*?

Comment: No sorry. Actually line 4, the importing of `rdf-parse` fails, as written in the post.
I also made the minimal example therefore. 
I am pretty sure, that my rollup config is not precise enough (I mean, thats the difference between `dev` and `build`), but I tried so many different configs and no one worked.